# How can I vectorize the following calculation?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

Suppose there is a value `n` input from a user and it goes in to the following `for` loop code. Is there a way to vectorize the following code?

```
A = 1:n
B = [1 1;1 1]
for i = 1:n
    B = B + A(i)*B;
end
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's have a look at a specific example:

```matlab
n = 5;
A = 1:n;
B = [1 1; 1 1];
for i = 1:n
    B = B + A(i) * B;
end
B
```

The result is:

```
B =
   720   720
   720   720
```

First of all, I would re-write the loop:

```matlab
n = 5;
A = 1:n;
B = [1 1; 1 1];
for i = 1:length(A)
    B = B * (A(i) + 1);
end
B
```

That way, it's more obvious, that your loop variable `i` simply iterates all elements in `A`.

Also: `B + A(i) * B` is the same as `B * (A(i) + 1)`.

Now, we see, that inside the loop, you're basically calculating:

```
B = B * (A(1) + 1) * (A(2) + 1) * (A(3) + 1) ...
```

The product over all elements in `A` (or here: `A + 1`) can be simplified by using MATLAB's [`prod`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/prod.html) function:

```matlab
n = 5;
A = 1:n;
B = [1 1; 1 1];
B = B * prod(A + 1)
```

Let's check the result:

```
B =
   720   720
   720   720
```

In that very special case for `A = 1:n`, the product `prod(A + 1)` is simply the [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) of `n + 1`, such that we could also use MATLAB's [`factorial`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/factorial.html) function:

```matlab
n = 5;
B = [1 1; 1 1];
B = B * factorial(n + 1)
```